# What java api generates 'o.a.c.b.converters' logging?

Tags: slf4j

Does anybody know which java api generates this output.

```
  19:41:29.367 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.converters.BooleanConverter - Setting default value: false
  19:41:29.373 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.converters.BooleanConverter - Converting 'Boolean' value 'false' to type 'Boolean'
  19:41:29.373 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.converters.BooleanConverter -     No conversion required, value is already a Boolean
  19:41:29.377 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.converters.ByteConverter - Setting default value: 0
  19:41:29.377 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.converters.ByteConverter - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Byte'
  19:41:29.378 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.converters.ByteConverter -     Converted to Byte value '0'
  19:41:29.379 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.c.CharacterConverter - Setting default value:  
  19:41:29.379 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.c.CharacterConverter - Converting 'Character' value ' ' to type 'Character'
  19:41:29.380 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.b.c.CharacterConverter -     No conversion required, value is already a Character
```

I've a large maven project with a lot of dependencies but the pom.xml hasn't changed today, but my unit test output now includes this junk. End of a long day but I can't see what's causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full classpath is `org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters`

Comment: What a pleasant surprise, 5 years later!